# Expression for "pulling out something from the past"

Tags: idioms, expression-choice, proverbs

I am looking for an expression (proverb / idiom) meaning "pulling out something from the past"  in disapproval.

An example of this would be: somebody mentioning a thing of the past, which is not relevant anymore. Do we have a proverb / idiom with this meaning?

Comment: I find this unintelligible. Do you have a friend who speaks English and can rephrase this so it makes sense?

Comment: Hello Mr. Landesberg: I have tried to rephrase the question. Have I made it better?

Comment: @JohnM.Landsberg - I think he means to say that someone pulls "something" out from the past to quote in a conversation or otherwise but that "something" doesn't hold any relevance in the present or in the context. Sort of a meaningless anecdote.

Comment: Thanks for reworking it. It makes sense now. I'll venture an answer in a moment.

Comment: @Mohit: I am looking for an equivalent of No. 22 in http://blogs.transparent.com/hindi/idioms-in-hindi-ii/

Comment: You mean no. 27.

Comment: Mr. Landesberg, you are correct.

Comment: Mr. Landesberg was a talented comedian and actor, first name of Steve, who unfortunately passed away in 2010. I'm Landsberg (without the first "e"), my good fellow, but John will do. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only things that spring to mind are these:

> "That's a dead issue."

or

> "I thought that was dead and buried."

and

> "Stop beating a dead horse," or, "You're just beating a dead horse."

Somewhat related to this might be:

> "That was old when Moses was a boy."

Comment: Rekindle the past.

Answer (score 5):

One might say the person is "Digging up bones" or "Raking up the past" or failing to "let it die".

Answer (score 2):

**[ˌdredge something​ˈup](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/dredge-up)**

> *(usually disapproving)* to mention something that has been forgotten,
>   especially something unpleasant or embarrassing
>
> *The papers keep trying to dredge up details of his past love life.*

[Dredge up the past](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=%22dredge%20up%20the%20past%22&tbm=bks) is a [common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=dredge%20up%20the%20past&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdredge%20up%20the%20past%3B%2Cc0) expression

---

If you're set on an idiom, try:

**[reˌopen old ˈwounds](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/wound)**

> to remind somebody of something unpleasant that happened or existed in
>   the past
>
> *His comments have served only to reopen old wounds.*

(Oxford ALD)

Answer (score -1):

Some other suggestions, which might suit according to different contexts:

> Don't drag that up again / He's always dragging that up.

or

> That's old hat.

or

> Stop raking over stuff.

Answer (score -3):

“Whoever forgives an offense seeks love, but whoever keeps bringing up the issue separates the closest of friends.“
-Proverbs17:9

Comment: Well, yeah, that *is* a proverb, but in its entirety, and having a different meaning.